# IN does not act as an OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following script and I want to filter the results only for the analysts that I have included the in statement:

```
select count(distinct t1.ticketid),t2.BuilderAnalystID AS iDS
from ticket as t1 inner join
Timepoint as t2 on t1.ticketid=t2.TicketID
 where 
     (InternalTicketStatusID=4 and
     (TicketStatus like '%closed%' or ticketstatus like '%resolved%'))
     or
     (InternalTicketStatusID<>4 and
     (TicketStatus like '%closed%' or ticketstatus like '%resolved%')) AND
     SubmissionToDT>='04-01-2017' AND
     SubmissionToDT<='07-12-2019' AND
     (t2.BuilderAnalystID not like null
      and t2.BuilderAnalystID in (1,3,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,186,193,233,234,235,236,237,238))
      group by t2.BuilderAnalystID
```

However, in the results that I get back I see the ids for all analysts not the ones that I have included in the IN statement. I am also seeing the id of null!
Any clue why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Your parentheses are not balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you formatted your code consistently, you would immediately see the problem:

```
where (InternalTicketStatusID = 4 and
       (TicketStatus like '%closed%' or ticketstatus like '%resolved%'
       )
      ) or
--------^  Alert!  The following conditions do not apply
      (InternalTicketStatusID <> 4 and
       (TicketStatus like '%closed%' or ticketstatus like '%resolved%'
       )
      ) AND
      SubmissionToDT >= '2017-04-01' AND
      SubmissionToDT <= '2019-07-12' AND
      (t2.BuilderAnalystID not like null and
       t2.BuilderAnalystID in (1,3,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,186,193,233,234,235,236,237,238)
      )
```

Your first condition (in parentheses) is not connected to the rest.  The parentheses are off.

This is why I match closing parentheses with opening parens.

I also fixed the date constants as well.

Comment: Just want to place extra emphasis (friendly) on the comment about formatting code consistently.  Becomes more crucial as the complexity increases.  And also important so the next person who looks at your code (which may be you) doesn't have to spend a 30 extra minutes deciphering it.  I've lost many work hours properly formatting someone else's SQL statements into a readable format.

Comment: What do you mean by "Your first condition (in parentheses) is not connected to the rest. ", @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @nina_dev . . . You essentially have `X or Y`.  "X" consists of two clauses.  "Y" consists of all the other clauses in the query.

Comment: @DBro there are many great tools now you can use to auto-format sql. Here is a free one. http://poorsql.com/ They also make an SSMS plugin. Many other tools out there can help with formatting code so you don't have to do it manually like we used too.

Answer (score 1):

`t2.BuilderAnalystID not like null`  yield null and not true
and in where clause only true and false response are evalueted  logical operation

could be you mean

```
AND  ( t2.BuilderAnalystID is not  null

   and t2.BuilderAnalystID in (1,3,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,186,193,233,234,235,236,237,238))
```

or better

```
AND  t2.BuilderAnalystID in (1,3,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,186,193,233,234,235,236,237,238)
```

Comment: This seems like what they mean. But of course the first predicate is pointless because any row can't be one of those values AND NULL.

Comment: The NOT NULL is redundant. Any of those values by definition is NOT NULL.